# Do SpringBoot Configuration Trees support refresh

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kubernetes

Do SpringBoot [Configuration Trees](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#features.external-config.files.configtree) support refresh?

I have the following. If the `/mnt/secrets/` volume changes does Spring automatically refresh Beans with `@ConfigurationProperties`?

```
spring:
  application:
    name: "foo"

  # Read Secrets
  config:
    import:
      - configtree:/mnt/secrets/
    activate:
      on-cloud-platform: kubernetes
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently if a Kubernetes configmap or secret is modified/updated, it does not redeploy the pod automatically. There needs to be a manual deployment to pick the new changes.

This is currently a feature in progress to facilicate this. https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/22368

So going by above, can you see if your case falls on the same lines. If so, check if below helps.

From a Kubernetes perspective, you can use Reloader to look for changes and auto redeployment.

For now, use Reloader - https://github.com/stakater/Reloader

It watches if some change happens in ConfigMap and/or Secret; then performs a rolling upgrade on relevant DeploymentConfig, Deployment, Daemonset, Statefulset and Rollout

How to use it - https://github.com/stakater/Reloader#how-to-use-reloader